# How to generate table rows dynamically using react.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, iteration

Currently, I am generating both the table header and the rows but I want to make the rows little more dynamic. How can I print the data of the rows without iterating more than once? how can I do it using 1 statement just like the header? So basically I would just call '{row}' and it should generate everything that row contains instead of having to type '{row.school}' etc...

```
const schoolData = [
 { school : 'Middle School', year : '2017', date : '6/12/17', location : 
'Class',},
{ school : 'High School', year : '2017', date : '2/24/17', location : 
'Gym',},

];


export default class Table extends Component {

render() {
const headers = Object.keys(schoolData[0]).map(header => 
<TableHeaderColumn>{header}</TableHeaderColumn>);

return (
  <Tabs>
<Tab label="School Type">
<Table>
  <TableHeader>
    <TableRow>
      {header}
    </TableRow>
  </TableHeader>
  <TableBody>
    {schoolData.map( (row) => (
      <TableRow>
        <TableRowColumn>{row.school}</TableRowColumn>
        <TableRowColumn>{row.year}</TableRowColumn>
        <TableRowColumn>{row.date}</TableRowColumn>
        <TableRowColumn>{row.location}</TableRowColumn>
      </TableRow>
      ))}
  </TableBody>
</Table>
```

Comment: Post the code for your `TableRow` component. What you would likely do is modify that class so you can simply pass it a "row" object and it constructs its own `TableRowColumn`s internally.

Comment: there is no code for that all the code is above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Object.values(obj)`, which receives an object and return an array of every `value` of every `key: value` in that object.

So you could do:

```
{schoolData.map(row => (
  <TableRow>
    {Object.values(row).map(rowValue => 
      <TableRowColumn>{rowValue}</TableRowColumn>
    )}
  </TableRow>
))}
```

You can always sort the array returned by `Object.values(row)` before the map. But the order is pretty consistent anyway I think. Or you could parse your `row` object into an array sorted the way you want, and then do `sortedRow.map(...)`.

But we're starting to get a little more than just one line of code, aren't we? Your way is faster to write and simpler to read, but doing it this way is a little more maintainable later, whatever suits you best is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use `Object.keys` this way. The output of `Object.keys`is ordered arbitrarily and is not guaranteed to be consistent between objects that have the same shape:

```
Object.keys({foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar', baz: 'baz'})
// -> ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
Object.keys({bar: 'bar', baz: 'baz', foo: 'foo'})
// -> ["bar", "baz", "foo"]
Object.keys({ baz: 'baz', bar: 'bar', foo: 'foo'})
// -> ["baz", "bar", "foo"]
```

There are many approaches to this problem. One way is simply to pass a multi-dimensional array to the component:

```
[
    ['header1', 'header2', 'header3', 'header 4'],
    ['row 1 cell 1', 'row 1 cell 2', 'row 1 cell 3', 'row 1 cell 4'],
    [...],
]
```